# Return a single column that matches a parameter

Tags: sql-server

In a stored procedure scenario, I would like to return a single column that matches a specific condition while assigning that column the appropriate name.

- The problem with the following technique is that it returns all columns including those that do not match the condition and assign null values to them.

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT
  CASE WHEN @ColumnName = 'A' THEN s.suborderid END AS ColA
  , CASE WHEN @ColumnName = 'B' THEN s.orderid END AS ColB
  , CASE WHEN @ColumnName = 'C' THEN s.envelopeid END AS ColC
  ```

How to return only the first column that matches the @ColumnName parameter in this case?

**Updated** with a **[Demo](http://rextester.com/COQW41049)**

*The goal is to return the ReadyDesc column only.*

Comment: you will need to do a dynamic query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a IF .. ELSE IF block in your stored proc

```
IF @ColumnName = 'Ready'
BEGIN
     SELECT DISTINCT Ready  As ReadyDesc
     FROM #ImagesTable
END
ELSE IF @ColumnName = 'Quality'
BEGIN
     SELECT DISTINCT Quality As QualtiyDesc
     FROM #ImagesTable
END
```

Edited your **[Demo](http://rextester.com/edit/SWQ80551)**

Comment: I like the IF ELSE technique, but what if the FROM statement is large and complex. Will I have to repeat it two or more times?

Comment: You can insert the records that come from complex FROM statement in temporary table / table variable and use that inside IF ELSE Block instead of writing the statement again and again in IF ELSE block

Comment: Will that affect the performance since this will require selecting ALL records first and then run another SELECT with DISTINCT added?

Comment: I think there would be not much performance hit as you are applying distinct on single column in every IF ELSE block. Also you can limit records being inserted by using WHERE clause if applicable

Answer (score 1):

Using `Dynamic Query` should the return the column you asked for.

```
create table  #ImagesTable(
Quality nvarchar(50),
Ready nvarchar(50))

-- insert into the temporary table
INSERT INTO #ImagesTable(Quality,Ready)
Values
 (1, 1), 
 (1, 1), 
 (1, 1), 
 (1, 1), 
 (1, 1), 
 (1, 0), 
 (1, 0), 
 (1, 0),
 (1, 0), 
 (1, 0);

DECLARE @ColumnName nvarchar(50) = 'Ready';
declare @mysql nvarchar(max)

select @mysql = N'Select distinct ' + @ColumnName + ' from #ImagesTable';

execute sp_executesql @mysql

drop table #ImagesTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly **Dynamic SQL** or an extended CASE would be more performant, but the following is Dynamic without actually going Dynamic.

**Example**

```
DECLARE @ColumnName nvarchar(50) = 'Ready';

Select Distinct C.*
 From  #ImagesTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Field = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') in (@ColumnName )
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
Field   Value
Ready   0
Ready   1
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165599/discussion-between-john-cappelletti-and-usefulbee).

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, it appears that S.O does not send chat notifications. However, I ran the query today against a data set with over 170 thousand rows, and it took over 2 minutes to return the result. That is 258782 CPU, 6237 Reads, and 130787 duration. Strangely, last week when I tested it, it was faster but still as slow as 20 secs.

Comment: @usefulBee Sorry didn't see any chat notification.  Even 20 seconds would be too long for me unless it was in a scheduled batch process.   Dynamic may be the way to go.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, Right. The dynamic approach returned the result in around 2.5 seconds while the IF ELSE approach done it in .5 seconds, when no temporary table is used.

Comment: @usefulBee Seems like the IF is the hands down winner eventhhought it is ugly.  Temp tables should still be available  ...  Select * From  Tempdb.Sys.Columns Where Object_ID = Object_ID('tempdb..' + @TempTable)  ....